# Solve $3^x+x^3=17.$

Tags: algebraic-equations

It's a question I find a bit difficult to solve, and the question is:

$$3^x+x^3=17.$$

Comment: @user772702 Are you asking for x?

Comment: If the right side was $18,$ you’d have to use numeric methods to approximate the solution. But as it is, we can just try a low integer value of $x$ and get the answer.

Comment: Yes. Try guessing some  low counting numbers and quickly eliminate numbers.

Answer (score 0):

17 can be split into 9 and 8. To get 8, 2 to the power of 3 is 8. To get 9, do 3 squared. 8+9=17. So x is 2.